# I can't extend Form

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I started using android studio recently, and I'm following [this guide](http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/05/convert-app-inventor-java/) but I can't seen to extend form, android studio highlights form in red and gives me the option to alt+enter. Once I alt+enter to import form, it show

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
```

but the guide show

```
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"alt-enter" will give you options that are available on your local build. The tutorial gives you the assets and if they are not properly placed in your project, then this will not work.

You should be able to manually add the import:

```
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Form;
```

If that fails, then I would assume that you did not properly add the ".jar" file in the tutorial. There are several ways to add jars (like put it in the "libs" folder). Do a search and you can select what works best for you and it should fix your problem.

Once it's properly imported into your project, you should see that import as an option. If you don't but manually entering it works, maybe restart Android Studio if that happens. Either way, you should have a good build at that point, and that's what matters.